# Struts2: repopulating textboxes with List<Integer> after validation

Tags: java, javascript, struts2

I have a JSP page which has code like this::

```
 <div id="TextBoxesGroup">                                      <div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="inputAuto">Room type</label>
<div class="controls">
<!-- <input type="text" id="inputAuto" class="grd-white" /> -->
<s:select id="inputAuto" data-form="select2" cssStyle="width:200px" data-placeholder="Select Room Type" name="resortRoomtype" headerKey="-1" list="roomtypeList"/>
</div>

</div>

<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="inputAuto">Room Numbers</label>
<div class="controls">
<!-- <input type="text" id="inputAuto" class="grd-white" /> -->
<s:textfield id="inputAuto" cssClass="grd-white" name="roomnumbers" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>
<s:label name="roomNumberError" cssClass="help-inline" cssStyle=" color: red;"></s:label>
</div>

 </div>

</div>

<div >
  <input type='button' value='+' id='addButton' Class="btn " />
                                                      <input type='button' value='-' id='removeButton' Class="btn" />
</div>
```

my js for add and remove button is::

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#addButton").click(function () {
           if( ($('#TextBoxesGroup').children().size()+1) > 12) {
             alert("Resort don't have more rooms" );
               return false;
                 }
           var id = ($('#TextBoxesGroup').children().size()+1).toString();
            $('#TextBoxesGroup').append('<div class="control-group" id="control-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="inputSelectGroup">Room Type</label>

 <div class="controls"><select style="width:200px" id="inputSelectGroup" name="resortRoomtype" data-form="select2"> 
    <option value="Single Room">Single Room</option>
    <option value="Double Room">Double Room</option>
    <option value="Twin Room">Twin Room</option>
    <option value="Interconnecting Room">Interconnecting Room</option>
    <option value="Suite">Suite</option>
    <option value="Pent House Suite">Pent House Suite</option> 
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group" id="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="inputauto">Number of rooms</label>
     <div class="controls">
     <input type="text" Class="grd-white" id="inputauto" name="roomnumbers"
     onkeypress="return  isNumber(event)" >

     </div>
    </div>');

         });


           $("#removeButton").click(function () {
               if ($('#TextBoxesGroup').children().size() == 2) {
                  alert("No more textbox to remove");
                    return false;
                     }

                $('#TextBoxesGroup').children().last().remove();
                $('#TextBoxesGroup').children().last().remove();
                    });
                });

 </script>
```

and in my action class i've ::

```
private List<Integer> roomnumbers;
getter/setters;
```

and i've a validate method which will validate that is there any field is empty or not. if empty then it will return INPUT and I'll be back to my form page (e.g. add_resort.jsp). So for ex i have input like for a roomtype :: single room roomnumber is ::2 and for roomtype :: doubleroom roomnumber is:: empty (i forgot to enter number) and then I click button save changes and validation happenes..
but when i return to that page in my roomnumber text field i got value something like this:::**[2,null]**

test case::::::

before validation
roomnumber =2

after validation
roomnumber=[2]

test case::::::

before validation
roomnumber =2
roomnumber= null

after validation
roomnumber=[2,null]

in validate method

```
if(roomnumbers != null){
roomnumbers.add(new Integer(55));
setRoomnumbers(roomnumbers);
addFieldError("roomnumbers", "Please Enter valid room number.");
}
```

Comment: While posting a question on SO, kindly try to make formatting the text convenience to read.

Comment: sorry for this but It's my 1st question on SO, so It's happend. btw can you give me sol for my prob.???

Comment: in my 2nd test case ..using javascript i am adding 1 more textbox in which i'm inserting nothing..and in my default textbox i'm inserting 2

Comment: Where is your validation related code?