# Why we cannot change anything in validate method In Struts2?

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts2-interceptors

In Struts2 `validate` method is called before `execute` method.
But why we cannot change any field value in `validate` method?

Comment: any reason you want to change that in validation section, though that is not a good approach at all

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi I have to remove some null values while validating.In my case I've a list<Integer> in which I've two vales 1 & 2 and I am adding one more value in validate method I'm adding 55 to the list and displaying this value on my result type input page where I'm getting [1,2] not [1,2,55]. so thats why I'm confuse.

Comment: You should not use validate() method for it(Code should be cohesive).
If you need to do the same thing for multiple Action classes/ View pages, keep such cross cutting concerns( like aspects) in a separate custom Interceptor and configure this Interceptor to be called before your Action classes. Still I feel using Interceptor is not a good solution and hope to find something better here.

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena the interceptors you speak of would need to be configured based on the type of methods in the action, that indeed would be a bit tricky, if you were to create such interceptors fortunately the framework takes this into account already when setting params: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/type-conversion.html also see these type conversion annotations" http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/annotations.html

Comment: @prtk_shah no one is putting a gun to your head and saying you _can't_ alter field values in the validate method. It just isn't the intention of the method and will clutter it. Putting the prepare interceptor after the params interceptor and before validation, then doing that kind of manipulation there... at least people would expect changes to the actions state to occur there, but as I suggested to Shailesh with proper type converters in place you shouldn't need to do any clean up.

Answer (score 4):

Any particular method should do one thing. A `validate()` method should *validate* data - it should check whether it's correct, not try to fix it up. The result of validation should simply be a pass or a fail; if it does anything else, it's doing too much.

(This isn't specific to Struts at all - it's the general meaning of validation, IMO.)

Comment: i'm looking for a technical answer...but thanks for the answer @Jon Skeet

Comment: @prtk_shah: The point is that the design of Struts (forcing validation to be pure) is just following natural principles.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly agree with @jon Skeet, a validate() method is meant to do validation only.

But to answer @prtk_shah's question i would like to add that if you are using validate() method of ActionSupport class, you can change field value in validate method using the following example:

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{
private String userName;
private String password;
//getter setter
@Override
    public void validate() {
        super.validate();
        if(getUserName()==null){
            setUserName("abc");
        }

    }
}
```

By default, validate() method will return the "input" string, but if the result is mapped to the "input" in struts.xml, then you can get your field value in welcome.jsp by using this code:

```
<s:property value="userName"/>
```

**Note:** The above example can be used to achieve what you have asked in the question, but validate() method is used for validation purpose only.

Comment: you both are true. but in my case I've a list<Integer> in which I've two vales 1 & 2 and I am adding one more value in validate method I'm adding 55 to the list and displaying this value on my result type input page where I'm getting [1,2] not [1,2,55]. so thats why I'm confuse..

Comment: Can you please type your code, so that i can test it here.

Comment: you can see it here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606284/struts2-repopulating-textboxes-with-listinteger-after-validation

Comment: By default the validate method doesn't "return" to anything-it *can't*. The result after the validate depends entirely on the workflow interceptor and the content of the action messages and errors.